# in pinia(the vue store), how can i set an object to pinia state

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs3, pinia

when i code like this. it do works. the data in pinia is updated

```
let thePerson = this.store.getPersonById(this.personId); //
thePerson.id_card = this.person.id_card;
thePerson.name = this.person.name;
thePerson.contact = this.person.contact;
thePerson.gender = this.person.gender;
```

but when i use any of these, it not work.

```
//thePerson = Object.assign({}, this.person);
//thePerson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.person));
//thePerson = { ...this.person }; not work
```

is there any short way to do this?

ps. the store is here(ignore the //):

```
state: () => ({
    machineCode: "",
    mac: "",
    business: {},
    // persons: [
    //   {
    //     id: 1,
    //     type: "MOTHER",
    //     name: null,
    //     ethnicityCode: null,
    //     idCard: null,
    //   },
    //   {
    //     id: 2,
    //     type: "FATHER",
    //     name: null,
    //     ethnicityCode: null,
    //     idCard: null,
    //   },
    // ],
```

Comment: You should not use any of the above 3 ways for assignment to `thePerson` because they remove/destroy the reactivity. As a side note - Pinia is completely unrelated to Quasar. You may want to remove the `quasar` tag from your question.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks man. but i do want to find a short way to do this to not consider the tedious assignments.

Comment: What tedious assignments, can you explain? The store is reactive - once you initialize it, you can read and write the state directly without any getters and any actions (https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#modifiable-state) It's very much like a component-local data access.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, just like i said. i'd like to just do:  thePerson = this.person. //sth like this.

Comment: Then perhaps you can simply use [reactive()](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) instead of Pinia?

Comment: Can you please share your store too?